# How to enable gerrit hooks plugin?

Tags: git, hook, gerrit

Hi I am running gerrit server by docker image (gerritcodereview/gerrit:3.2.3).
I accessed with "docker exec" and made  "/var/gerrit/hooks" directory and executable files "commit-received, patchset-created, ref-update, submit" to use gerrit hooks plugin.
But all hooks don't work even when it should be. Do I have to modify more to use gerrit hooks plugin?

And I have one more question. Is there any plugins to use pre-submit hook in gerrit?

Answer (score 0):

Step 1 Config your hook path in Gerrit config file

```
[hook]
     path = /xxx/hooks
```

Step 2 Make your script *executable* in the path folder **without any extension**

Doc is [supported hooks](https://gerrit.googlesource.com/plugins/hooks/+/HEAD/src/main/resources/Documentation/hooks.md)