# Gerrit webhooks configuration

Tags: webhooks, gerrit

I am trying to configure webhooks in Gerrit from the admin side. Still not able to find a perfect solution. PFB referred doc:

[How to Configure Gerrit Webhooks for gerrit events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65575218/how-to-configure-gerrit-webhooks-for-gerrit-events)

Is it like once we configure from the backend, we will get an option to enable in the individual repo?

Can anyone help with this?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should ENABLE webhooks in Gerrit and no need to do that again in Repo.

Config the hook path in gerrit.config and put your scripts with right names.

see details from https://stackoverflow.com/a/68465416/5121698

Answer (score 0):

Create a webhook.config file in meta/config branch of the project
The following information should be added to the content of the file:

```
[remote "jenkins_name"]
  url = https://<jenkins_domain_name>/hibernation/queue/<jenkins_name>/gerrit-webhook/
  event = patchset-created
  event = ref-updated
  event = change-merged
```

Remarks:

- If Gerrit is running in the cloud, you have to specify the full URL to your Jenkins instance.
- Multiple Jenkins instances can be specified as remotes.
- The URL to Jenkins is always like "/gerrit-webhook/".
  The relevant steps to set up your Jenkins Multibranch pipeline are described in [Gerrit Code Review](https://plugins.jenkins.io/gerrit-code-review/). This also includes the communication back from Jenkins to Gerrit (setting verified status, automatic comments on the patchset).
- A list and description of events can be checked on the [official documentation](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/cmd-stream-events.html#events).
  Some more information (mainly manually triggering the hook) is described [here](https://bigbrassband.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/GITCLOUD/pages/628523026/Adding+webhooks+for+Gerrit).

Using webhooks with tokens

There is a plugin for Jenkins [Multibranch Scan Webhook Trigger](https://plugins.jenkins.io/multibranch-scan-webhook-trigger/) that allows to use tokens with the webhook triggers inside the multibranch pipelines. This is useful if you have several jobs connected to a repository but you don't want to trigger a scan of all of those jobs when making a commit to the repository (e.g. start a scan only for the main job, but not for a nightly testjob). For this you have to follow these steps:

- Create the multibranch pipeline and select the option "Scan by webhook" and specify a token. In addition it might be helpful to also set the option "Periodically if not otherwise run" so that there is still a regular scan of the repository.
- Adjust the URL in the webhooks.config file like below:

> [remote "testsse1"]
> url = https://testsse1.jenkins.com/devops/multibranch-webhook-trigger/invoke?token=<your_token>